# Balls in $(X, d)$ and $(X, \overline d)$, where $\overline d (x, y)= \min\{1, d(x, y)\}$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, solution-verification

Consider the standard bounded metric on $X$, that is, $\overline{d} = \text{min} \{1, d(x,y)\}$ where $d$ is also a metric on $X$.

Let $B_d(x,r)$ be the $d$- open ball and $B_{\overline{d}} (x,r)$ be the  $\overline{d}$-open ball. I want to prove that

$$B_d\left(x, \frac{\text{min} \{r,1\}}{2}\right) \subset B_{\overline{d}}(x,r)$$
and
$$B_{\overline{d}}\left(x,\frac{\text{min} \{r,1\}}{2}\right) \subset B_d(x,r).$$

My attempt:

I want to prove  $B_d(x, \frac{\text{min} \{r,1\}}{2}) \subset B_{\overline{d}}(x,r)$.

Let $y \in B_d(x, \frac{\text{min} \{r,1\}}{2})$, then $d(x,y) < \frac{\text{min} \{r,1\}}{2} < \frac{1}{2} <1$, hence $d(x,y) < 1$, so by the definition of standard bounded metric $\overline{d}(x,y) =d(x,y)$. Also, we have $d(x,y) < \frac{r}{2} < r$, hence $\overline{d}(x,y) < r$, therefore $y \in  B_{\overline{d}}(x,r)$. So, we conclude that $B_d(x, \frac{\text{min} \{r,1\}}{2}) \subset B_{\overline{d}}(x,r)$.

Is my proof correct?

But I cannot proceed for a proof of $B_{\overline{d}}(x,\frac{\text{min} \{r,1\}}{2}) \subset B_d(x,r)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me, the first part of your proof is correct.

For the second question, instead of showing

$$B_{\overline{d}}\left(x,\frac{\text{min} \{r,1\}}{2}\right) \subset B_d(x,r)$$

I will show that

$$X\setminus B_d(x,r) \subset X\setminus B_{\overline{d}}\left(x,\frac{\text{min} \{r,1\}}{2}\right)  $$

which is equivalent.

Take $y\in X\setminus B_d(x,r)$. We have $d(x,y)\ge r$, so:
$$\overline{d}(x,y) = \text{min} \{1,d(x,y)\} \ge \text{min} \{1,r\} \ge \frac{1}{2}\text{min} \{1,r\}$$
Which gives $y\in X\setminus B_{\overline{d}}\left(x,\frac{\text{min} \{r,1\}}{2}\right)$, QED.